# Steps to move a commit from one branch to another as changes

Tags: git

Normally if I make changes in a branch and realize I meant to do it in a different branch, then I can simply stash the changes and then checkout the branch I want.

How do I effectively accomplish the same thing if I've already committed locally (but not pushed to remote)?

I want my local branch to be as though I never made any changes... in particular I don't want to have to push two commits (one with the changes, and one that reverts the changes). I just want the commit to go away as if it never happened. And when I checkout the branch I want, I want my changes to be there... or I want to be able to restore them (as changes, but not as a commit, obviously).

I've done some searching and the answers I've found primarily focus on the first case I mentioned where changes weren't committed. It's very possible I've run across the exact answer I need, but didn't realize it because I wasn't 100% if the scenario was the same as mine. So obviously I'm a bit new to git and I'm sure this has got to be a duplicate question, but maybe I am just having trouble identifying which existing questions are the duplicates with confidence.

Also I tagged vs 2017 and 2019 because I use both and welcome any answers that explain how to do this through the IDE in either of those versions in additions to how to accomplish this in a shell.

This particular commit is the only one. Though I am interested to hear solutions for both scenarios (this one, and one where I had other valid commits).

Answer (score 31):

Things to keep in mind:

- Git traffics in commits. Not changes. Not files. Commits.
- A branch is just a label for one commit.
- You can move a branch, attaching it to any commit you like, with `git reset`.

Let's start with a two-branch situation:

```
% git log --oneline --all --graph
* 102fa13 (br) z
| * 7e0ddf5 (HEAD -> master) d
| * 3a460a5 c
|/  
* e7547cb b
* 0bcb421 a
```

So I regret that `c` and `d` were made on `master`; I wish they had been on some other branch. So I can think of two main scenarios here. Does that other branch already exist or not?

If not, then simply make the new branch here (where `master` is now) and slide `master` back down to before `c`:

```
% git branch newbranch
% git reset --hard e7547cb
```

Result:

```
% git log --oneline --all --graph              
* 102fa13 (br) z
| * 7e0ddf5 (newbranch) d
| * 3a460a5 c
|/  
* e7547cb (HEAD -> master) b
* 0bcb421 a
```

That's the easy case. The harder case is that the other branch already exists: let's say it's `br` in the first graph above. Then *rebase* the `c` and `d` commits onto `br`. After that, reset `br` up to where `master` is now, and then slide `master` back down to where it was before `c`:

```
% git rebase --onto br e7547cb master
% git switch br
% git reset --hard master
% git switch master
% git reset --hard e7547cb
```

Result:

```
% git log --oneline --all --graph
* f9ff4a0 (br) d
* 5c43690 c
* 102fa13 z
* e7547cb (HEAD -> master) b
* 0bcb421 a
```

Note that the `d` and `c` commits here are copies (they have new unique ids); that's inevitable when you move commits around, as commits themselves are immutable.

Comment: Many people use Git without even knowing the basics. Once you know some basics, Git is actually quite transparent. It has many complex and surprising corners, but basic usage is straightforward once your mental image of it is accurate. I’m sure my approach in this answer is ludicrously verbose, but hopefully it’s clear to you what I’m doing and what it does and why.

Comment: Many people are forced to use GiT without the benefit of formal training. Inevitably leading to a mental model that I call the reluctant wizard. Thus the many requests for incantations on SO and so forth.

Comment: @davidjmcclelland I don't know that formal training matters. I'm just saying it's a good idea to have a generally correct picture of what Git is. When you do, a lot of answers become trivially obvious.

Comment: didn't work, happily rported OK but lost all my commits

Comment: @teknopaul I don't know what your situation is; this answer was directed at the question that appears at the top of this page. If you have a new question (including how to get your commits back, it's easy), hit the Ask Question button at the top right and ask it.

Answer (score 17):

You may cherry-pick your commit on the current branch to the other branch, then nuke the commit on the current branch.

```
# from current branch, get SHA-1 of latest commit (e.g. ABCD1234)
git log
git checkout other_branch
git cherry-pick ABCD1234

# now return to original branch and nuke commit
git checkout current_branch
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

Notr that this answer strongly relies on that you *haven't* yet pushed the current branch with the mistaken commit.  If you have done this already, the answer would need to change.

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce the second case (where have made the commit) to the first case (where you have not yet made a commit):

Undo the commit, but keep the changes:

```
git reset HEAD^
```

At this point, you have removed the unwanted commit and restored the current branch to the state without the commit.

Also, you have now uncommitted changes, and you are on the "wrong" branch, i.e., you have now "the first case".

Then transfer the changes to the other branch:

```
git checkout -m other-branch
```

The option `-m` does the magic. At this point, you have uncommitted changes that you can commit.

Comment: Tried this because it seemed simplest. Didn't work as expected but that may be my fault (not sure?). One thing I didn't make clear is I already took an action that created a new commit to revert the previous one. I tried "git reset HEAD^" but I was in Windows cmd prompt where ^ has special meaning that screws it up. I read elsewhere "HEAD~1" would produce same effect so I tried that but it only removed the "revert" commit. So I did same command again and they were both gone. Great... except the commits weren't converted back to changes. They were just gone as if I never changed anything. :(

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation, where 2 branches had branched off of the same *stage* branch at different points in history. Branch A had a single commit not in stage, and branch B had 3 commits not in stage. I wanted the last two commits of branch B to be placed in branch A.

Both branches, A and B, were now behind stage because stage had gotten other branches merged into it. I made the mistake of merging stage into A, and B, because I thought that they sharing the tip o stage would help makes things easier. It did not.

When I tried to rebase (following the instructions in [@matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67444266/1195463)) the two commits I wanted from branch B, I ended up with the two commits, plus a bunch of new commits coming from merging stage into B, and this was giving me unwanted merge conflicts during the rebase. To solve this issue, I added the `-i` option to be able to edit the todo list, and just `drop`ped the commits that I did not want. The rebase completed with no issues, and no merge conflicts.

I'm leaving this answer here in case someone comes here with a case like mine.